# removeing repository addded by add-apt-repository

Tags: ubuntu, debian, repository, apt

I just added a repository on my **Debian 10** and I wanna remove it right now. The command was `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thopiekar/sierrabreeze`.
How do I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the repository using the command
`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:thopiekar/sierrabreeze`